# max upload size from iPhone to server

Tags: iphone, file-upload

Does any one know what is the max file size we can upload to a server from an iPhone app?

I could easily upload a file with size upto 10 MB but app start giving unpredictable results in uploading a video beyond this size.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there would not be any limits on the file size from the iPhones side of view. However you might have limitations imposed on you from the server side, e.g max disk quota, etc.

You will have to implement the upload in chunks or streamed as the iPhone is limited in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload end read the file from disk in chucks, the limiting factor will be the server and you internet connection.
I don't think that there is a hard limit to the upload.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no limit. Just make sure that the server that you're sending the data to is configured to accept it.